# In C#, how do I make my button's text dynamic?

Tags: c#, button, textbox

I'm a newbie when it comes to coding C#, so please don't be too harsh on me. I've coded with ActionScript before, and notice that it's very similar.

Anyway, I need to basically build a simple application where 2 characters give each other "money"... or ints. The character name should be dynamic, and the buttons should play off of what the names are.

Please help! This is what I have so far:

```
namespace Lab_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Guy firstName;
        Guy secondName;
        int bank = 100;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            firstName = new Guy() { Cash = 100, Name = "Joe" };
            secondName = new Guy() { Cash = 50, Name = "Bob" };

            firstName = textBox1.Text;
            secondName = textBox2.Text;

            UpdateForm();
        }

        public void UpdateForm()
        {
            name1CashLabel.Text = firstName.Name + " has $" + firstName.Cash;
            name2CashLabel.Text = secondName.Name + " has $" + secondName.Cash;
            bankCashLabel.Text = "The bank has $" + bank;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Give $10 to " + firstName.Name;

            if (bank >= 10)
            {
                bank -= firstName.ReceiveCash(10);
                UpdateForm();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The bank is out of money.");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bank += secondName.GiveCash(5);
            UpdateForm();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            secondName.ReceiveCash(firstName.GiveCash(10));
            UpdateForm();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstName.ReceiveCash(secondName.GiveCash(5));
            UpdateForm();
        }

        private void name1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstName.Name = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you which to update the button text? I somehow don't get the meaning of your question...

Comment: Given the namespace is this homework?

Comment: Also `Name = textBox1.Text;` what/where is `Name`?

Comment: Ah - its got the homework tag now - nm.

Comment: It's not homework actually. I'm learning from the Head First C# book for my own sake.

Comment: I fixed the Name = textBox1.Text. It should have been firstName = textbox1.Text; For some reason, that leaves the button blank, when I want it to update the firstName dynamically.. if that makes sense

Comment: You can't assign a string (which textbox1.Text is) to an object of type `Guy`.  That won't compile.  Does it compile for you as it stands now?

Comment: It does compile, but no text shows up on button1. There are 0 errors. Part of the chapter talks about being able to assign a new Name for the buttons dynamically. http://cl.ly/d63add050ce81120fc67

Comment: Would it just be easier to use a combobox? I feel like this is going to be impossible.

Comment: I don't think a combobox will help you at all, unless I've completely missed the question (very possibly, possibly likely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna just show new names on buttons, you can update them so simple like so:

```
private void name1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    firstName.Name = textBox1.Text; 
    button1.Text = "Give $10 to " + firstName.Name;
}
```

And maybe the same for `name2_click` (if you have):

```
private void name2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    secondName.Name = textBox2.Text; 
    button2.Text = "Give $10 to " + secondName.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key bit seems to be the `name1_Click` method which updates the firstName object's Name to the contents of the textbox.  Once you've done that you want to refresh the button's caption.

I'd create a new method:

```
public void RefreshButtonCaptions()
{
    button1.Text = "Give $10 to " + firstName.Name;
    button2.Text = "Give $10 to " + secondName.Name;
}
```

And then call it from `name1_Click`:

```
private void name1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstName.Name = textBox1.Text;
    RefreshButtonCaptions()
}
```